# Audio encoding technique of VoIP and Walkie-Talkie

Tags: audio, encoding, voip, audio-streaming

Is audio encoding technique of **VoIP(Voice over IP)** and **Walkie-Talkie** same?

what are the audio-encoding/decoding techniques of VoIP and Walkie-Talkie?

Answer (score 0):

Anything digital has to use a codec to transform an analouge voice signal into digital information, which varies from program to program. The encoding of the Walkie-Talkie will often vary from model to model, but there's an interesting article about them at http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/walkie-talkies.htm